# How should I save references to firebase storage objects?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

1. Store references by name (users/1/profile.png). Then the URL needs to be generated all the time.

```js
const url = await firebase
  .storage()
  .ref('users/1/profile.png')
  .getDownloadURL()
```

2. Store references by URL. The access token could be revoked which would cause issues trying to generate a new one and update it in the database.

```js
const url = await firebase
  .storage()
  .refFromURL(invalidURL)
  .getDownloadURL()
```

3. Related to #1. Store by file name only so files can be moved without having to update database references.

```js
const url = await firebase
  .storage()
  .ref(`users/${user.id}/${user.image}`)
  .getDownloadURL()
```

Comment: Do whichever one suits your needs the best.  The both have advantages and disadvatanges, as you're discovering.

Comment: I'm mostly perplexed by needing to call `getDownloadURL()`. I'm not sure if there are performance or cost concerns calling that method frequently.

Comment: That's something you can benchmark on your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The download URL and the reference path are two different things and I'd store each of them as appropriate (and sometimes both).

Store the **Download URL** when you want to directly serve the file from storage (e.g. an `<img>` tag).

Store the **Reference Path** when you need to keep a reference to the file to modify it later.

Calling `getDownloadURL()` does trigger a network request and so it's advisable to cache the result when possible to avoid unnecessary extra work/latency.

Comment: Ditto here: I'd keep the path if you need to for example edit the image (as it avoid a lookup), and the download URL if you need to share the image for someone to read (as it avoid an expensive lookup). Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52252520/firebase-cloud-storage-download-url-vs-path/52260317#52260317